# Entry Level Physics Texts

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

Fellow Physics community, I am an undergraduate about to graduate with an Econ major & Math minor. I have never taken a physics class at the university & it bugs me how ignorant I am about the physical word. I am planning on picking up some Physics textbooks once I graduate to educate myself out of this state.

My question: Given that I have already taken the Calculus Series + Linear Algebra/Diff Eq’s classes & read their textbooks, what are some good entry level **Physics Texts** that don’t dumb the math down to purely algebra?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/207455

Comment: see Dr Physics A on youtube.